# React app works on local but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app works perfectly in local, without errors, but when I try to deploy it on netlify or github pages, when I open it, the page is blank and many errors are displayed in the console.

The error says

> TypeError: can't access property "length", e is undefined

where *e* corresponds to *items* (which is a state).

If I remove these lines of code, I get another error that always concerns *items*: the problem this time is with *items.some*, where *items* is *null* again.

Whatever I try to do *items* always result *null*.
I tried *console.log(items)* in many component files and in all of them the result is *null*.

This is the netlify link where you can see the error:
https://celadon-otter-917b4e.netlify.app/

**Navbar.js, where the error is located:**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Searchbar from './Searchbar';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import FavoritesContext from '../FavoritesContext';

function Navbar() {
    const { items } = useContext(FavoritesContext);

    return (
        <div className='navbar'>
            <Link to={'/'} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                <div className='logo-container'>
                    <img src="/foglia.png" alt="logo" className='logo'/>
                    <h3>just<span>vegetables</span></h3>
                </div>
            </Link>
            <Searchbar />
            <Link to={'/favorites/'} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                <h4 className='favor'>Favorites: <span>{items.length}</span></h4>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
} 

export default Navbar;
```

**FavoriteContext.js:**

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FavoritesContext = createContext();

export function FavoritesProvider({ children }) {

    const [ items, setItems ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const recipesFavorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites-recipes'));
        setItems(recipesFavorites);
    }, []);

    const saveToLocalStorage = (item) => {
        localStorage.setItem('favorites-recipes', JSON.stringify(item))
    }

    const addToFavorites = (title, image, id, favorite) => {
        if (!favorite) {
            const newFavoriteList = [...items, { title, image, id }]
            setItems(newFavoriteList);
            saveToLocalStorage(newFavoriteList);
        };
    };

    const removeFromFavorites = (title, image, id, favorite) => {
        if (favorite) {
            const newFavoriteList = items.filter((fav) => fav.id !== id);
            setItems(newFavoriteList);
            saveToLocalStorage(newFavoriteList);
        };
    };

    return (
        <FavoritesContext.Provider value={{ items, setItems, addToFavorites, removeFromFavorites }}>
            {children}
        </FavoritesContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default FavoritesContext;
```

**Card.js**:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import FavoritesContext from '../FavoritesContext';

function Card({ title, image, id }) {

    const { addToFavorites }  = useContext(FavoritesContext);
    const { removeFromFavorites }  = useContext(FavoritesContext);
    const { items } = useContext(FavoritesContext);

    const checkIsAdd = () => {
        if(items.some((val) => val.id === id)) {
            return true;
    }};
    
    const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(checkIsAdd);

    const isInFavorites = (id) => {
            return (
                <img src='../cuore-pieno.png' alt="like" className='favorite blue' onClick={() => {removeFromFavorites(title, image, id, favorite); toggle()}}/>
            )
    }

    const toggle = () => {
        isInFavorites(id);
        setFavorite(!favorite);
    }

    return (
        <div className='card'>
            {!favorite ? <img src='../cuore-vuoto.png' alt="like" className='favorite' onClick={() => {addToFavorites(title, image, id, favorite); toggle()}}/> : isInFavorites(id)}
            <Link to={'/recipe/' + id}>
                <img src={image} alt='' className='card-image'/>
                <div className='card-info-cnt'>
                    <p className='card-title'>{title}</p> 
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projetto-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://michela-z.github.io/justVegetables",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-env-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --env mode=development",
    "prod": "npm run webpack -- --env mode=production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',  
    entry: {
        index: {
            import: './src/index.js',
            dependOn: 'shared',
        },
        another: {
            import: './src/another-module.js',
            dependOn: 'shared',
        },
        shared: 'lodash',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: port,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
    },
};
```

I'm new to programming, this is my first react app, I tried everything that was in my ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there item present before checking its length `{items.length}`
you can achieve this by

1. `{item && item.length}`  or
2. `{items?.length}`

this will get rid of the errors displayed in live deploy

Comment: It works!!! I used this condition every time 'items' appeared in the code, because in any case it blocked the whole application because it was null. Thank you!